# SharePoint 2010 REST URI won't return data for only some lists, why?

Tags: 2010, infopath, rest, odata

When creating lists in SharePoint, do you have to enable the REST service feature per list or something similar?

I have one SharePoint list that returns data fine using REST, the URI is loosely as follows:

```
http://server/sites/ect/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Users
```

and I've copied over this data to a new list in the same area with the same data, however I gave it a new name (this is for testing purposes), but it will not return any data using the same basic REST call:

```
http://server/sites/ect/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/UsersTest
```

They are almost completely identical, but one refuses to return data, is there something I didn't know to enable when creating the list?

Comment: What is the title of the second list? Is it UsersTest or something else. Note that title can be different from Url.

Comment: This is in fact the name of the list, all I did was add `Test` to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you navigate to the service root you'll see all the lists that are exposed by the service.

/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/

Comment: It's there: `- <collection href="UsersTest">
  <atom:title>UsersTest</atom:title> 
  </collection>`

Answer (score 0):

try to create a list without test on the name. Seems the web service does not like the word "test" . Probably some security reason.